# how to fix a while loop that clicks a button but yields a 'ElementClickInterceptedException:' after the first iteration

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am webscraping https://www.virginmobile.ca/en/phones/phone-details.html#!/a70/Black/128/MTH. I am trying to grab the pricing under 'PICK YOUR MONTHLY PHONE PLAN' however as I select the 'buy your phone upfront' option the plans below have a 'see more plans' button which I am attempting to click. I managed to click it it however sometimes there is still more plans to be seem and my while loop doesnt seem to click it if the button still exists. instead the trace states:

Element  showitems" ng-click="showmoreplans()" ng-bind-html="messages['phonedetail.seemoreplan.label']" class="ng-binding ng-scope">... is not clickable at point (620, 870). Other element would receive the click: ...

```
    for planType in planTypeRawList:
        planPriceList = []

        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(planType).click().perform()
        time.sleep(0.5)

        while True:
            try:
                see_more_plans = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#planList > a')))
                see_more_plans[0].click()
                print('see More Clicked')
                time.sleep(0.5)

            except TimeoutException:
                break

        planPriceListRaw = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#planList .price')))

        for price in planPriceListRaw:
            planPrice = price.text
            planPriceList.append(planPrice)

        print(planPriceList)
        print('end of plan type')
```

I would ultimately like to be able to click the 'see more plans' option as much times as it pops up and then move on to scrape after all the plans are visible and the button disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to element using `location_once_scrolled_into_view` method before clicking.

change your code as below.

```
see_more_plans = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#planList > a')))
# you don't have to scroll to element when you are using the javascript
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",see_more_plans[0])
print('see More Clicked')
```

Comment: location_once_scrolled_into_view seems to have no effect

Comment: Well the reason being not able to see the effect is due to the fixed div at the bottom. Try with the updated answer.